# Send a picture to Facebook using Graph API on Android

Tags: android, facebook, upload, facebook-graph-api, photo

I have been searching for this all day and just when I find something, I find it is not what I am looking for. In short, I am upgrading my app to use the Facebook graph API for Android and the documentation is horrible. All I want is to upload a picture into the default album for the app. I have the following code:

```
Facebook f = new Facebook(APP_ID);
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", caption);
parameters.putByteArray("picture", data);
f.dialog(mContext, "publish.stream", parameters, this); //TODO: This is wrong
```

I think the publish.stream is what is the problem because the exception that I got when I did my "this doesn't have a prayer" test was a malformedURLException.

Can someone tell me if I am even on the right track?

Thanks,
Jake

Comment: Did you get already access_token for you app (and register it as the facebook app)? You can find some info [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)